# Refresh ListView after changing listItem

Tags: android, listview

I am new to programming/Android and I am trying to refresh a ListView after editing the listItem from a DialogFragment window. Here is where the ListView is defined:

```
public class AnswersList extends AppCompatActivity {

private ListView mListAnswer;
private AnswerAdapter mAnswerAdapter;
private static final String ANSWERS_TO_LISTVIEW = "answers_to_listview";
private static final String TAG = "AnswersList";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_answers);

    mAnswerAdapter = new AnswerAdapter();

    mListAnswer = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    mListAnswer.setAdapter(mAnswerAdapter);

    // handle clicks on listview
    mListAnswer.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int whichItem, long id) {

            Question tempQuestion = mAnswerAdapter.getItem(whichItem);

            // create a new dialog window
            DialogShowAnswer dialog = new DialogShowAnswer();
            // send in a reference to the Note to be shown
            dialog.sendQuestionSelected(tempQuestion);

            // Show the dialog window with the note in it
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "");

        }
    });


}

public class AnswerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<Question> mListAnswers = new ArrayList<Question>();
    QuestionBank mQuestionBank;
    Context mContext = getApplicationContext();

    public AnswerAdapter() {
        mQuestionBank = QuestionBank.get(mContext);
        mListAnswers = mQuestionBank.getAnswers();
    }

    public ArrayList<Question> getListAnswers () {
        return mListAnswers;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mListAnswers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Question getItem(int position) {
        return mListAnswers.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ** A bunch of code here **

        return convertView;
    }

    public void updateList() {
        mListAnswers = mQuestionBank.getAnswers();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


}


}
```

Here is the code for the dialog window:

```
public class DialogShowAnswer extends DialogFragment {

private Question mQuestion;
private static final String KEY_INDEX = "index";
private static final String TAG = "DialogShowAnswer";

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if(savedInstanceState != null) {
        mQuestion = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_INDEX);
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_show_answer, null);

    TextView questionText = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.questionAnswerDialog);
    TextView answerText = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.answerAnswerDialog);
    TextView dateText = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dateAnswerDialog);
    final Button btnClose = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
    final Button btnSave = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    ImageView editIcon = (ImageView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editIcon);

    btnSave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    questionText.setText(mQuestion.getQuestion());
    answerText.setText(mQuestion.getAnswer());
    dateText.setText(mQuestion.getDateString());

    builder.setView(dialogView);

    editIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ViewSwitcher switcher = (ViewSwitcher) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.viewSwitcher);
            final EditText editAnswer = (EditText) switcher.findViewById(R.id.editAnswerDialog);

            if(btnSave.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                btnSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                btnSave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            switcher.showNext(); //or switcher.showPrevious();
            editAnswer.setText(mQuestion.getAnswer());

            btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String answer = editAnswer.getText().toString();

                    if (answer.length() > 0) {

                        mQuestion.setAnswerDate();
                        mQuestion.setAnswer(answer);

                        QuestionBank questionBank = QuestionBank.get(getContext());

                        questionBank.updateQuestion(mQuestion.getId(), mQuestion);

                        AnswersList callingActivity = (AnswersList) getActivity();
                        callingActivity.getAdapter.updateList();

                        Log.d(TAG, "notifyDataSetChanged() called");

                        dismiss();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.empty_answer_field, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                }
            });

        }
    });

    btnClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });



    return builder.create();
}

public void sendQuestionSelected(Question question) {
    mQuestion = question;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if(mQuestion != null)
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable(KEY_INDEX, mQuestion);
}


}
```

I've been stuck on this for days. All help appreciated!

Comment: Another related question: Why can't I call the updateList() defined in the first code block from the second code block. updateList() is a method of the nested BaseAdapter class in the first block. When I try to call it in the second block (callingActivity.getAdapter.updateList();) Android Studio says it can't resolve it.

Comment: I knew there was a simple solution to get the ListView to update and I figured it out. Instead of:
    callingActivity.getAdapter.updateList();
it should be:
    ((AnswersList.AnswerAdapter) callingActivity.getAdapter()).updateList();

Answer (score 0):

[I assume Question Bank](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) is a contentprovider/contentresolver. See the notifyChange method in the link? this method fires a dataset change event. A listener [such as this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) hears the event and re-loads the data/cursor. Maybe not exactly what you want but maybe this will help lead you in the right path.

Comment: QuestionBank is a singleton that creates a sqlite database of question/answer/id rows and also pulls and updates those rows. Would a content provider fill the same role?

Comment: Thats exactly what a contentprovider does. Now assume a screen orientation change happens in the middle of a query. Do you want to wait till the query finishes then redraw the screen making yet another query or use a content provider. I suggest you look into a code generator utility such as https://github.com/BoD/android-contentprovider-generator this kind of utility or ones like it (google contentprovider generator) will right the code for you, you input tables and columns. contentresolver is used to do the actual query Cursorloader is another thing you can look into.